# Is there a maximum amount of RAM Mathematica can manage?

Tags: memory, hardware

We are performing full diagonalization of large matrices using Mathematica, in order to study certain statistical measures of eigenstates in certain problems of quantum physics.

We have been using Mathematica 11 on a Red Hat Linux machine with 100 GB of RAM, which has allowed us to deal with matrices up to ~ 35,000 x 35,000 in size. That machine is nearing the end of its life due to hardware issues, and we want to upgrade.

Is there a maximum to the amount of RAM that Mathematica 12 can manage? I.e., if we purchase a machine with 1 TB or more of RAM, running Red Hat Linux (the only flavor supported by IT at our university), or Windows 10, will we be able to utilize all of this memory? Or is there a limitation due to management issues?

We need full diagonalization of non-sparse matrices for the research problem we are working on.

Comment: I'd think there's no maximum other than that defined by the 64-bit pointers used on x86_64. And RHEL 8 supports up to 24 TiB of RAM, see [their spec on limits](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-limits#maximum-memory-2).